# Whats the minimum size sample required for a LSTM RNN model?

Tags: dataset, lstm, rnn

I have a data set of 100 rows x 100 to 300 columns. Will an LSTM RNN model work for my data or do I need more data?

If my sample size is a problem are there other RNN architectures capable of modeling using small dataset sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on the actual data and on the chosen hyperparameters (e.g. hidden size, regularization). Only experimentation will tell you if you can get good performance.

There is nothing inherently wrong with using an LSTM with small data but, given how small your dataset is, you will probably need a small hidden size and a lot of regularization to avoid overfitting.